# where to store photos, in database or in api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs, fs, gridfs

I'm currently working on creating a website for my college. I want to include a galary section on the page.
so through admin page, authorities can upload photos of special college events. Now my question is where to store those images. I have two options 1)storing in the Database using gridfs 2) storing in the api. I have done a lot of research on this topic but everyone saying it depends on the situation. What do you think the best option for this situation. I'm still new to server side programming, so please help me. I'm using nodejs with ejs and mongodb

Comment: I'd store them in the server file system or in a cloud file storage such as S3, and refer to the paths in the database.

Comment: @AKX i dont know we can store paths in db . any way thanks for the reply

Comment: Paths are just strings, why wouldn't you be able to store them in the database? Heck, you can just store the URLs that your eventual `<img>` tags would have...

Comment: In MongoDB, database files for images (photos), videos, documents (PDF, doc, etc.) can be stored, queried and retrieved using the GridFS.